# how to echo a char instead of key pressed in JTextField

Tags: java, swing

I need to echo a particular character instead of the key pressed in `JTextField`.
the effect produced is like I press `k` key but `*` appears in the textfield.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.Please read the FAQ before asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a [`JPasswordField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html) instead? It's a subclass of `JTextField`

> that allows the editing of a single line of text where the view indicates something was typed, but does not show the original characters.

(Quote from Javadoc)

Regarding the addition that characters need to be transformed dynamically, you might want to look into the example of an `UpperCaseField` with an `UpperCaseField` from the [Javadoc for `JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html). It can quite easily be transformed into some logic that transforms every character to another one.

Comment: I want to print something else everytime key is pressed and also use it as text field after certain condition is met

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your first addition. Regarding the latter, maybe replace the `JPasswordField` with a `JTextField` (be it read-only or not) once your condition is met. You can always get the text a user entered, even when it's a `JPasswordField`.

Comment: it should work like : 'k' key pressed output 'a' in text area ,then press 'l' output append 'b' in text area and continue this process

Comment: @user2076400 If this is what you want, kindly update your question accordingly. Your question (current version) only speaks of replacing 'k' with '*'

Answer (score 1):

You neet to use [`JPasswordField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html) for this. Using the [`setEchoChar(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#setEchoChar%28char%29) you can echo any character you want.

**Update** As per the [OP comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702527/how-to-echo-a-char-instead-of-key-pressed-in-jtextfield#comment22299457_15702572), if the requirement is to echo different character based on differen key pressed by the user, `keyTyped` event can be used, as below:

```
sampleTextBox.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
            event.setKeyChar(getCharToEcho(event.getsetKeyChar())); 
                            // getCharToEcho(char inputKey) will return the key to
                            // echo depending upon the key entered by the user
        }
    });
```